# What is I/O of web server

Tags: io, webserver, cpanel

My site hosted in a shared hosting. From cpanel's resouce usage option, I can see that I/O limit for my site is 4096 and in peak time, my site often reaches to its I/O limit. As I don't know much about it and as I didn't find any details article about it after googling, I was unable to optimize my php scripts to reduce the I/O. The only thing I know about it, is Input-Output Process.
Would someone explain it what is I/O and how can I reduce I/O?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Isn't this something you should be asking your hosting provider?

Comment: My hosting provider said they don't help for web developing issue. I think most of the hosting providers say this, they don't take any responsibility for optimizing scripts, they just know to suspend your shared hosting saying just a word "Your site is utilizing over resources and thus suspended".

Comment: I'm not saying you should get them to solve it but it's their responsibility to tell you what and how they're _measuring._ Then, armed with that, you can ask a more intelligent question :-)

Comment: I asked them, they would not tell anything details without it's elaboration, Input-Output Process. They advised me for googling, but I didn't find any useful article/document regarding I/O of a webserver. I found 1/2 useful article for PC, but those do not make any sense for a web server.

Comment: Seriously? You need to ditch these clowns and find a better provider. If they won't even tell you what they're measuring, how the hell are you expected to know if they're lying?

Comment: Yes, I think so too. But I am with this hosting provider for last 2 years and did not face this type of suspension of over resource usage problem, from last one month I am  facing this problem for which I am loosing my visitors as it is being suspended in peak time for over usage of server resources. They gave me domain at free and I already renewed my hosting for 01 year, thus I am unable to left them right this moment. After googling I found that most of the shared hosting providers are same in nature, they just suspend and do not answer their customers properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using MYSQL for database? In that if you are using "select * from .......", change it to something that you only need. For example "select name from...". The * operation will return a lot of data that will increase the i/o usage. So optimize the queries. Also in some php scripts there will be multiple queries, check whether they can be minimized.

Another reason is due to high resolution images. If you are having high resolution images, either reduce their size or upload those photos to flicker or any website like that which will give hot link to that image. Then use it in your website. So i/o usage form your server will be reduced

Comment: Thanks Gijo for your answer. May I know, If I do a INSERT query and then check the operation by mysql_affected_rows() or $mysqi->affected_rows, is that a second query after INSERT query or this is just a single query?

Comment: No its a single query. Insertion will not increase much i/o usage. Mainly select command. Also if you application is inserting too much of rows per second, the mysql will automatically lock.

Comment: Sorry I forgot. Done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've already encountered this error and this is the best solution I've found:

In your root folder (probably called public_html)please add this code to your .htaccess file...

REPLACE the 00.00.00.000 with YOUR IP address. If you don't know your IP address buzz over to What Is My IP - The IP Address Experts Since 1999

```
#By Marky WP Root Directory to deny entry for WP-Login & xmlrpc
<Files wp-login.php>
        order deny,allow
        deny from all
        allow from 00.00.00.000
    </Files>
<Files xmlrpc.php>
        order deny,allow
        deny from all
        allow from 00.00.00.000
    </Files>
```

In your wp-admin folder please add this code to your .htaccess file...

```
#By Marky WP Admin Folder to deny entry for entire admin folder
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 00.00.00.000
<Files index.php>
        order deny,allow
        deny from all
        allow from 00.00.00.000
    </Files>
```

From: https://www.quora.com/I-am-using-shared-hosting-and-my-I-O-usage-is-full-after-every-minute-What-is-this-I-O-usage-in-cPanel-How-can-I-reduce-it

Answer (score 0):

In a shared hosting environment, or actually in just about any system, the I/O will be the read and write speed measure from the disk to the memory.

This limit is often limited in share hosting environment using the CloudLinux LVE technology.

Since WordPress sites are using a lot of files in the back end and every plugin will also add more files (and let's not forget your theme). The I/O limit can rocket sky high very quickly.

On WordPress site, there many plugin that will enable cache for your pages. Therefore, instead of reloading every php page on each load, the server will be able to send a static page created from your cache plugin. This will reduce your hosting IO by a lot.

NOT some plugin like W3 Total Cache is very efficient on old PHP version, but will not work on PHP7 on up. One paid plugin which is worth taking a look at is WP Rocket.

I hope this help understanding what IO’s are!